# boot problem, encrypted xubuntu, grub reinstall

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, encryption, reinstall

I tried to start a new Fedora live from usb and after this I a have problem with my encrypted Xubuntu.

I guess that this is a problem with grub but I don't know how to reinstall it.

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BBD97191-7592-436E-9009-FBE74CD2E753
Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda3  2050048 1953523711 1951473664 930.5G Microsoft basic data
```

What should I do step by step to reinstall grub?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done [manually](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) but the recommended way is via the Boot-Repair tool.

Try this steps using `Boot-Repair tool`:

1. create an `Ubuntu live-USB`
2. boot into that `live-USB` and select `Try Ubuntu`
3. After Ubuntu lunches bring up the terminal and run the following commands:

   - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
4. launch the Boot-Repair from `dash` or `terminal` or sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &) -- to install and repair at once
5. click the `recommended repair button`
6. When finished just shutdown and boot normally from your system

**NOTE: As instructed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) please do not alter any settings on the Boot-Repair tool just use the recommended ones**

Hope it helps.

Go here if you need further links [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Take note of the url When repair is finished, (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper you might need it if it didn't go as expected.

Comment: GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.

What now? should I create small partition and flag it as boot?

Comment: yes please it needs that. Remember don't format it.

Comment: ant luck @CezaryG ?